# Batch File [scheduled task] copying all .txt files under a rot directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I've got .txt files in lots of subdirectories and these directories keep receiving new files [logs] but old ones are not deleted.

I need to keep synchronizing the files under the various subfolders with a folder containing all .txt files. As we have a lot of files and they keep being created and not deleted, I wonder is there a .bat file code I can use and schedule to run each minute in order to keep these files in sync? Is it better to somehow use robocopy?

Comment: Do you want to delete files from one location or the other, or keep them perfectly in sync?

Comment: @mojo I can't delete them, I need to keep them in sync.

Comment: `robocopy /MIR` should mirror the content (including removing files in the target location if they cease to exist in the source).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many computers you need to run this on I would suggest using something like Microsoft SyncToy2.1 to sync the files and then just delete like normal in a batch file.

For example, create a folder sync pair for each folder and then then call the process using a batch file followed by a delete:

```
“C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe -R"
/wait
Del c:\PathToTxtFiles\*.txt /f
Exit
```

Calling "SyncToyCmd.exe" with the -R switch will tell it to sync all the folder pairs and then running a delete command to clear out all your old files.  HowToGeek does a pretty good explanation on how SyncToy works and how best to set it up for your situation at:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25046/schedule-synctoy-to-run-automatically-with-task-scheduler-in-windows-7/

EDIT: I didn't notice where you said you dont want to delete them (I wasn't paying attention like I should)

In that case might I suggest two batch files name one sync.bat with the following two lines:

```
XCOPY "%1" "%2" /D /I %3
XCOPY "%2" "%1" /D /I %3
```

and a second one named anything with the following line:

```
SYNC "C:\My Project" "\\DELL\My Project" /S
```

The purpose is that the second one will call the first one with the parameters you put in the second (i.e. it will call xCopy for "C:\My Project" to the server share "\DELL\My Project").  The /D switch tells it to copy files that are newer from the source to the destination and if you don't want two way sync you could remove the second line; /I tells it that the destination is a directory (it keeps it from asking if it is a directory or file that you are copying to).  You could leave off the /S on the second one and leave out the %3 in the first one.

Tech-Pro.net has an article that explains it pretty well (using the same code I used) located here:
http://www.tech-pro.net/howto_033.html